# Apply function to rows return vector instead of list

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame (below is simplified version)

```
b<-data.frame('v1'=1:2,'v2'=3:4,'v3'=5:6)
```

If I use apply on rows:

```
test<-apply(b,1,function(x) {if (x[length(x)]>0) return (x/x[length(x)]) else return (0)})
```

I got:

```
[,1]      [,2]
v1  0.2 0.3333333
v2  0.6 0.6666667
v3  1.0 1.0000000
```

So far so good since I do need the column name v1,v2,v3 becomes row names in test.
But if the data frame is all zeros,

```
b1<-data.frame('v1'=c(0,0),'v2'=c(0,0),'v3'=c(0,0))
test<-apply(b1,1,function(x) {if (x[length(x)]>0) return (x/x[length(x)]) else return (0)})
```

test will return a vector as 0 0
My question is how to let test return something like

```
[,1]      [,2]
v1  0      0
v2  0      0
v3  0      0
```

Basically if the last one in a row is zero I want to make everything in the row as 0 and more importantly I want the return is a list so that I got the v1,v2,v3 row names (I can change to data frame if the return is list), now the return is vector 0,0 I lost all the information of v1, v2, v3. Why all zeros make such a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a function that divides the dataframe by the last column and then substitutes NAs with zeroes?

```
prop_last_col <- function(df) {
        prop <- df / df[, ncol(df)]
        prop[is.na(prop)] <- 0
        return(prop)
    }

prop_last(b)
         v1        v2 v3
1 0.2000000 0.6000000  1
2 0.3333333 0.6666667  1


 prop_last(b1)
  v1 v2 v3
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
```

If you want it to be in the same format as your example you could just transpose the results.

Comment: thanks for the reply. That surely will work. I am just wondering why R treats differently when the last column are all zeros vs at least one is not zero. I hope someone can tell me the fundamental reason and direct way to solve this so I do not have to take extra step to convert NA to zero. By the way can I accept more than one solutions if so I can accept.

Comment: That is because you are returning a numeric vector of length one with a 0 whenever the last element of the row is zero. If the value is bigger than 0, you return an operation on the row (which keeps the names).  If you change the last return to `x * 0`, like in `test<-apply(b1,1,function(x) {if (x[length(x)]>0) return (x/x[length(x)]) else return (x * 0)})` you would get the result you want. However I think the code is a bit harder to read like that.

Comment: Oh, and you can only accept [one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)